# cannot reinitialize DataTable popup

Tags: jquery, datatables

At my wits end on this.
Merging the datatables model with some show/hide functions on the columns, sorting, grouping etc
To make a good report template.
Everything works great except this damn popup wont go away

DataTables warning (table id = 'leads'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable

When I merged the two scripts to get all the bells and whistles out of the Datables and jquery i had to alter the name of the table in the extra script, thus causing the error.

Here is the original script

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Convert tables with the class "datatable" into a jquery datatable (sorting, searching, filtering enabled)
    oTable = $("table#leads").dataTable( {
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bSort": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWitdh": true,

        "fnInitComplete": function(){


            $("table#leads thead tr").each(function(){
                $(this).find("th").attr("nowrap","nowrap");
            })

            $("table#leads tbody tr").each(function(){
                $(this).find("td").attr("align","left"); // Centers all columns
                $(this).find("td:eq(0)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "25"); // Adds nowrap attribute to APP ID column
                $(this).find("td:eq(1)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "100"); // Icons & Flags
                $(this).find("td:eq(2)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "50"); // Agent column
                $(this).find("td:eq(3)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "15"); // Team column
                //$(this).find("td:eq(4)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "350"); // Company column
                $(this).find("td:eq(5)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "50"); // Amount column
                $(this).find("td:eq(6)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "75"); // Product column
                $(this).find("td:eq(7)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "50"); // Adds nowrap attribute to STATUS column
                $(this).find("td:eq(8)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "25"); // Div column
                $(this).find("td:eq(9)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "15"); // Channel column                
                $(this).find("td:eq(11)").attr("nowrap", "nowrap").attr("width", "15").attr("align", "center"); // Funding Coord column

            });
        }

    } ).rowGrouping({iGroupingColumnIndex: 10, iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: -1});



    // Reup filter functionality
    // Will filter the table down to the selected
    $(".reupFilter").on("change", function(e){
        var showFilter = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        if(showFilter == 1){
            oTable.fnFilter("ReUp");
        }else{
            oTable.fnFilter("");
        }

    });
});

function displayComments(leadid){

    $("#commentsContainer").load("/forms/partials/_queue_lead_comments.cfm?    leadid="+leadid);
    $("#commentsContainer").dialog({height: 450, modal: true, title: "Lead Status     Messages for "+leadid, width: 650});

}
```

Ok  here is the next script which i hade to give the name of the Table ID it needs to work on, Leads which is already in use by the last script.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('table#leads').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 15
    } );

} );


function fnShowHide( iCol )
{
    /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
    var oTable = $('table#leads').dataTable();

    var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );

}
```

Ok so i think i know what the problem is, 2 calls on the same table and its causing that error. Easy fix right, either remove 1 call (can't) or terminate the table.

So tried to terminate the first initialization of the leads table like so with no luck, just breaks the rowgrouping script.

`$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';`

Also tried this

```
$('#leads').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bDestroy": true
});
```

and also this

```
$(function leads () {

    $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'mute';    
});
```

In all 3 cases, simply breaks the RowGrouping script.

I think the answer is to make it a class instead and so be able to initialise 2 tables at a time. But i am not sure where to start on that. honestly I would settle for the damn popup to just go away, but as i said that only breaks the rowgrouping.

Sorry no link to offer, behind an intranet. Searched high and low for answers but, can't think of any other approaches or a code fix in 1 or both of these scripts.

Thanks for the help.

here is the supporting HTML

```
<h3>Sales Support Pipeline</h3>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="reupFilter" value="1" class="reupFilter">ReUp Only | <input type="radio" name="reupFilter" value="0" checked class="reupFilter"> All
</div>

<div class="row">

    <table id="leads" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>APP ID</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Agent</th>
                <th>TM</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Div</th>
                <th>Channel</th>
                <th>VIP</th>
                <th>Funding Coord</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <cfoutput query="getleads">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    #leadid#

                </td>
                <td nowrap>
                    <!--- Qualifier Img --->
                    <a href="edit_leads.cfm?leadid=#leadid#" target="_blank"><img src="/images/signin_16x16.gif" border="0"/></a>
                    <a href="../../forms/qualifier.cfm?CFGRIDKEY=#leadid#" target="_blank"><img src="/icons/account_16x16.jpg" border="0"></a>
                    <a href="actionlead.cfm?CFGRIDKEY=#leadid#" target="_blank"><img src="/icons/interest_16x16.gif" border="0"></a>
                    <cfif future_type EQ "Expedited">
                        <img src="/icons/burn.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" title="Marked as Expedited"/>
                    </cfif>
                    <cfif len(reup)>
                        <img src="/icons/reup.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" title="Marked as ReUp" style="display: none;"/>
                    </cfif>
                </td>
                <td>#trackid#</td>
                <td>#team#</td>
                <td>
                    <strong>#left(dba,50)#</strong>
                    <div style="font-size: 0.90em;">#left(corp_name,50)#</div>
                </td>
                <td>#iif(len(cashadv_amount), de(cashadv_amount),de("--"))#</td>
                <td>#gbr_product#</td>
                <td id="leadAction_#leadid#" class="action" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <span title>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="displayComments(#leadid#)">#application.services.leadService.getLastAction(leadid = getLeads, row = currentrow)#</a>
                    </span>

                </td>
                <td>#division#</td>
                <td>#apptype#</td>
                <td>#regular#</td>
                <td>#funding_coord#</td>

            </tr>
            <cfflush>
            </cfoutput>
        </tbody>
        <br>
<div class="trigger">
    <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="30%" class="display" >
    <tr bgcolor="#DAEFF0">
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);?y=2" onclick="fnShowHide(0);claim(0);" >AppID</a> </td>
    <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(1);claim(1);" >Icons</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(2);claim(2);" >Agent</a> </td> 
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(3);claim(3);" >TM</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(4);claim(4);" >Company</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(5);claim(5);" >Amount</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(6);claim(6);" >Product</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(7);claim(7);" >Status</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(8);claim(8);" >Div</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(9);claim(9);" >Channel</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(10);claim(10);" >VIP</a>  </td>
        <td> | </td> 
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0);"     onclick="fnShowHide(11);claim(11);" >FC</a>  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </table>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try using the `oTable` variable instead of the selector again. This way you are updating the current table instead of re-initializing it.

Comment: you mean like this? Not working
    $('#oTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
       "bDestroy": true
    });

Comment: no, like `oTable.dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 15
    } );`    Let me see if I can get a jsfiddle going. Otherwise, see if you can get a jsfiddle going as you know what you want

Comment: I also notice you are applying styles the hard way. Take a look at `aoColumns` (https://datatables.net/usage/columns). This will allow you to assign classes to each TD and also allow you to do special actions with the data if needed

Comment: If you could clearly state what result you want to get with your data. Perhaps some sample HTML and data would help us create tests to solve this problem. I have done some very custom complex systems with datatables. I'm just not clear on what you want.

Comment: tried that oTable but it just breaks the scroll bar

Comment: well i simply want the data table reinitialisation to go away. is there some other method to mitigate this double use issue? It doesn't seem to break anything just is a show stopper. i will add the supporting HTML

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this.

First, I notice you are not using server-side but then it looks like you switch to it. This example shows you how to set custom parameters in the request to use server-side, works great with the [Scroller](https://datatables.net/extras/scroller/) plugin but that may not be necessary or wanted.

From what I understand, you initially load the data on page load then apply datatables to the table. This example shows how to use server-side processing (my preference as it speeds up page load, pending the amount of data) but I left it commented out just as a reference.

It looks like your only issue is the re-initiation of the datatable...

Note the `oSettings` var below the `oTable` initiation. This allows you to have an instance of the `oTable` settings. You don't need to call `$('table#leads').dataTable();` as you already have `oTable` defined.

See if my code sample below will help you. I doubt it will work as copy/paste but I think you can see what I am getting at. Notice, I also showed you how to easily apply classes to columns. You may or may not care about that. It seems to have less overhead than your current method from my use cases.

```
oTable = $("table#leads").dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [
        [0,'asc']
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        {
            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "25px"
        },
        {
            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "100px"
        },
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "50px"
        },
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "15px"
        },
        null, // since eq(4) is commented out
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "50px"
        },
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "75px"
        },
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "50px"
        },
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "25px"
        },
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap",
            "sWidth": "15px"
        },
        null, // since eq(10) wasn't there
        {

            "sClass": "nowrap center",
            "sWidth": "15px"
        }
    ],
    "asStripeClasses": [], // removes classes for stripes (can be removed)
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bSort": true,
//        "bServerSide": true, // Not sure if you are using this but it seems you do change to it
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: sSource,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 0, // prevent timeout
            data: aoData,
            complete:function() {
                // Conditional logic goes here for completion
            },
            success: function (json) {
                /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                fnCallback(json)
            }
        });
    },
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        // Add parameters to the request
//            aoData.push( { "name": "leadid", "value": leadid} ); // uncomment if using server-side
    },
//        "sAjaxSource": "/forms/partials/_queue_lead_comments.cfm", // notice fnServerParams if using server-side. url is placeholder
    "sScrollY": 500
}).rowGrouping({
    "iGroupingColumnIndex": 10,
    "iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex": -1
});

// Load settings into an easy to access variable
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();

// make changes as you see fit
//  oSettings.sAjaxSource = "new value";
//  oSettings.bPaginate = true;
//  oSettings.iDisplayLength = 15;

// Reup filter functionality
// Will filter the table down to the selected
$(".reupFilter").on("change", function(e){
    var showFilter = $(this).val();
    if(showFilter == 1){
        oTable.fnFilter("ReUp");
    }else{
        oTable.fnFilter("");
    }
});

function displayComments(leadid){
    $("#commentsContainer").load("/forms/partials/_queue_lead_comments.cfm?leadid="+leadid);
    $("#commentsContainer").dialog({height: 450, modal: true, title: "Lead Status Messages for "+leadid, width: 650});

}

function fnShowHide( iCol ) {
    /* now we only use the settings object */
    var bVis = oSettings.aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

Personally, I use classes and assign them with js to the columns. This is easier by adding a classname to all columns so you can easily hide `.className`. `aoColumns` is where you add the class name.

Hopefully this will help you.